# Lumen error when adding a new artisan command and running the command as a scheduled task

Tags: laravel, command, scheduled-tasks, lumen, laravel-artisan

A file ExampleCommand.php is added under the console/Commands which is as per the laravel documentation,

Now in the protected commands section in console/kernal.php the new command is added

```
protected $commands = [
            Commands\ExampleCommand::class,
        ];
```

when php artisan schedule:run command was executed it gives the following error.

```
    lumen.ERROR: ReflectionException: Method App\Console\Commands\ExampleCommand::handle() does not exist in /var/www/html/busnet/Source/Main/Services/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php:135
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/busnet/Source/Main/Services/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php(135): ReflectionMethod->__construct(Object(App\Console\Commands\ExampleCommand), 'handle')
#1 /var/www/html/busnet/Source/Main/Services/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php(115): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::getCallReflector(Array)
#2 /var/www/html/busnet/Source/Main/Services/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php(29): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::getMethodDependencies(Object(Laravel\Lumen\Application), Array, Array)
#3 /var/www/html/busnet/Source/Main/Services/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#4 /var/www/html/busnet/Source/Main/Services/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Laravel\Lumen\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#5 /var/www/html/busnet/Source/Main/Services/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php(549): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Laravel\Lumen\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#6 /var/www/html/busnet/Source/Main/Services/vendor/illuminate/console/Command.php(183): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#7 /var/www/html/busnet/Source/Main/Services/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(252): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#8 /var/www/html/busnet/Source/Main/Services/vendor/illuminate/console/Command.php(170): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#9 /var/www/html/busnet/Source/Main/Services/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(946): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#10 /var/www/html/busnet/Source/Main/Services/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(248): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(App\Console\Commands\ExampleCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#11 /var/www/html/busnet/Source/Main/Services/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(148): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#12 /var/www/html/busnet/Source/Main/Services/vendor/illuminate/console/Application.php(88): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#13 /var/www/html/busnet/Source/Main/Services/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Console/Kernel.php(84): Illuminate\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#14 /var/www/html/busnet/Source/Main/Services/artisan(35): Laravel\Lumen\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#15 {main}  

In BoundMethod.php line 135:

  Method App\Console\Commands\ExampleCommand::handle() does not exist
```

Can any one help me out with the issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: ExampleCommand needs a handle method

Comment: Thank you @Indra I was using a fire method instead of handle method in ExampleCommand ,Now by using handle method it works perfectly.